# making new references in homepage magento

Tags: magento

[image: I want make new reference in the red one]

I want to make a new reference in the red area, I have added xml code in `page.xml`:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="newreference" as="newreference"/>
```

then i've put this script to `2columns-left.phtml`:

```
<div><?php getChildHtml('newreference') ?></div>
```

Then I've also put this xml into `page.xml`:

```
<reference name="newreference">
  <block type="catalog/product_under_wasis" name="home.product.under_wasis" template="catalog/product/under_wasis.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Then I put `under_wasis.phtml` into folder `catalog/product/`, but the result is still an error, `can't read 'newreference'`, what should I do?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function getchildhtml() in /home/sinergi/dev.sinergiprima.co.id/wasis/app/design/frontend/sinergi/hellowired/template/page/2columns-left.phtml on line 52

Answer (score 1):

Your `getChildHtml()` call is incorrect.

It should be:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newreference') ?>
```